# Export images with new bands from Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm trying to export images from an image collection after adding NDVI band with no success.

```
def addNDVI(image):# add NDVI band to collection
    return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B8A']).rename('NDVI'))

destination = 'Destination'

listOfImages = imageCollection.filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-01-02').filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE','equals','36RXU')

imageBand_ndviBand = listOfImages.map(addNDVI)
collectionList = imageBand_ndviBand.toList(imageBand_ndviBand.size())
collectionSize = collectionList.size().getInfo()


for image_num in range(0,collectionSize):
    select_Image = ee.Image(collectionList.get(image_num))
    Date_of_scene = select_Image.getInfo()['id'].split('_')[1].split('T')[0]
    task_config = {
        'region': ROI,
        'crs': 'EPSG:32636',
        'crsTransform':[20, 0, 600000, 0, -20, 3400020],
        'fileFormat': 'GeoTIFF',
        'fileNamePrefix':fileNamePrefix,
        'folder':destination,
        'image': select_Image.select(['NDVI', 'B2', 'B3']), # when i put a regular band instead of 'NDVI' it is working
        'description': 'imageToDriveExample_test'
    }

    out = batch.Export.image.toDrive(**task_config)
    process = batch.Task.start(out)
```

Comment: Please quote the error message you're getting, or otherwise explain how the code you have so far isn't working for you.

Comment: I am not getting any error message, just nothing happens and no file exported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that fit for me, hope it will help others.
The problem was that the new band, in this case 'NDVI' did not have the same scale.
So I rescaled all the bands in the image to one united scale:

```
select_Image.unitScale(0, 1)
```

and then export it to the drive